# why iScroll.js block page at load page?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, web, iscroll

right now, i'm using iscroll.js on my app page but for some reason it block scroll page until all DOM element is loaded. has some way to disable it?

Comment: Share code where you are loading and using it. Are you by any chance including it as script in `<head>`, without including script `async` attribute?

Comment: if you have elements without explicit width/heights i.e images you will run into problems with wrong scroller size if you try to do this